# want to create a Azure Logic App expression

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In Azure Logic App, I am creating blob event grid. I am able to get event whenever I have added or deleted a blob from a storage account. In that I am getting the below responses.

[image]

In the Subject i am getting response as **'/blobServices/default/containers/james/blobs/catputvendor/Capture.PNG'**

Now I need to write an expression which gets below result. 
**'/james/catputvendor/Capture.PNG'**. 
Which expression is best.

I got below expression using c# working but in logic app expression, we don't have Remove method. How I need to do in logic app as following:

```
var subStri1 = str.Remove(str.IndexOf("/blobs"), "/blobs".Length).Substring(str.Remove(str.IndexOf("/blobs"), "/blobs".Length).LastIndexOf("/containers") + "/containers".Length);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Subject` in the `Dynamic content`, it's the absolute path about the blob. So you could use `split` expression to get the path you want.

And the expression would be like this:`split(triggerBody()?['subject'], '/')?[4]`. My subject path is `/blobServices/default/containers/firstcontainer/blobs/test/Snipaste_2018-11-13_10-08-08.png`. So the expression will get the container name `firstcontainer`.

So the whole expression will be 
`@{split(triggerBody()?['subject'], '/')?[4]}/@{split(triggerBody()?['subject'], '/')?[6]}/@{split(triggerBody()?['subject'],'/')?[7]}`.

Here is my flow and the result page.

[image]
[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.